# Routes on server & client side - React.js & Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, react-router

I try to really understand how routes work with react-router on my react application and express on my node.js server.

React-router code :

```
import ..
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory, IndexRedirect, Redirect } from "react-router";

render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Redirect from="/" to="/index"/>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={NavBarTop} />
        <IndexRoute component={NavFilter} />
        <Route path="/index" component={Tickets} />
        <Route path="/ticket/:id" component={TicketInformations} />
        <IndexRoute component={InterventionsList} />
    </Route>
  </Router>,
document.getElementById('container'));
```

My server routing:

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/')), function(res, eq) {
});

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  console.log("test");
  var data = getTickets(); // return a JSON
  res.end( data );
});
```

my react routing works perfectly, however I want to make a AJAX call to fill my components. For this I try to get a JSON from my node server. However the path 'test' doesn't work. My console.log is not called.

I don't know why, I probably didn't understantd how it really works.
How can I create easily webservice to prepare my AJAX call ?

Comment: where is the call to "/test"?

Comment: in my node routing 'app.get('/test')'

Comment: you have to call that api from your client side app.other than that that wont be called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*ReactJS* applications are single-page applications (*SPA*) and, generally they are served from root ("/") of your *express.js* server. But, **unlike** any static webpage, a *SPA* don't call server for every route change, rather depends on *virtual routes* and it's own client-side route handlers. (*if you wonder, why SPAs don't refresh page, this is the reason behind, somewhat*). If a SPA uses any routes defined in its client-side route handlers, the *express* will always see it as the root route *"/"* and do nothing, actually it won't know anything, as browser won't make any request.

**React-Router** provides these *virtual routes* to *ReactJS* app.

In your code, when your React app goes from *"/"* to *"/index"* or any other routes defined using *React-Router*, it does not request *express* server for anything, rather everything is done over client-side/browser. That's why, even if you had a route defined as *"/test"* for *ReactJS*, it would not call server-side for anything.

(*by the way*, these *virtual routes* will also be used by *React* over server-side, if and only if you're using *React*'s server-side rendering. But, *express* will not know about these. *Express* will always behave the same, whether you use client-side rendering or server-side rendering.)

Now, lastly, if you want your *express* route *"/test"* to be called, you'll have to make a *fetch* request towards the route, thus the route will be called. (*have a look at [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch)*, if wondering which library to use)

*Hope these come handy*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! Everything is clear for me now. In fact I have to call a url in my AJAX call to fill my components, I imagined this solution (the route "/test" in my server). I will test isomorphic fetch. However is it a good way to do it in the react thinking ??

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question, I mean, what is the way you're asking to be a good way?

Comment: In fact I'm looking for a good way to fill my react component with data stored in my Mysql database. I though that AJAX call was a good way. So In my client side I call a url from my server which me return a JSON. However I juts began to inrfom me about the flux architecture. I'm a little bit lost so I asked if you think that make AJAX call in componentWillMount for example is a goog way to get data in react thinking in a flux architecture ? It look's weird to pass through a the isomorphic-fetch to call a url from my server. I have the feeling that it's not natural ...

Comment: React doesn't control data. Generally flux-implementations are used to control data. ReduxJS and RelayJS are most used flux-implementations. Your idea of fetching data when "componentDidMount" is wired and works, but your opinion is right. Use flux-implementations to handle data more structurally. Though flux-implementations will use "isomorphic-fetch" to receive data (if you use), but React will not be aware of that. (I know this is a self-promoting, but you can see https://marufsarker.github.io/blog/posts/2016/05/09/react-redux-with-graphql.html to know a little-bit about their works)

Comment: I will see that. Thank's for your help :)